# Cronjob in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cron, laravel-5.1, cron-task

I have the `job` table contains `post_at,day_open,block` properties

- The `post_at` property is the day when user post the job `(Ex:2015-11-24)`
- The `day_open` property is the day that job is open `(Ex:10)`
- The `block` property can contain 2 values 0 or 1. If `post_at + day_open > right now` the `block` value will change from 0 to 1

So how can I do that using cronjob?

Comment: Just use [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling). All you need to know, from setting up a the scheduler cron job to creating and scheduling commands is explained very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

First check wheather the post_at,day_open are edit in current date

```
$date = date('Y-m-d'); 
    $job= DB::table('job') ->select('post_at','day_open','block')->where('updated_at',$date) -first();
$id=$job->id;

    if(isset($job) && !empty($job)) 
    {
      $finding=CronJobCotroller::pushNotify($id);
    }
```

if it's true it go to function pushNotify under the CronJobCotroller,here we write the coding for changing block field value 0 to 1.

```
public function pushNotify($id) {


    $job= DB::table('job') ->select('block')->where('id',$id) ->get();

    if(isset($job) && !empty($job)) 
    {
      foreach ($job as $cb) 
    {
     $job= DB::table('job')->update('block',1)->where('block',0);

    }
    }
}
```